# Find spherical polar components of $\frac{\partial \textbf{F}}{\partial \phi}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I have to find the partial derivatives in spherical form of $\textbf{F}=r[\textbf{e}_{\theta}+\textbf{e}_{\phi}],$ and I managed to find all the others except for the one over $\phi$.

I got this far:
$\frac{\partial \textbf{F}}{\partial \phi}=r[\cos(\theta)\textbf{e}_\phi+\cos(\phi)\textbf{x}-\sin(\phi)\textbf{y}]$ , with the last two terms being the partial derivative of $\textbf{e}_{\phi}$ over $\phi$.

Since $\textbf{e}_{\phi} $ is an unit vector, its derivative has to be perpendicular to it, and as such must be of the form $A\textbf{e}_{\theta}+B\textbf{e}_r$, but if I try doing that I get that B must be both positive and negative.
Where do I go wrong?

Edit: calculation of coefficients

$[\cos(\phi),-\sin(\phi),0]=[A\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+B\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi), A\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)+B\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), A\cos(\theta)-B\sin(\theta)]$

From the third components:
$A\cos(\theta)=B\sin(\theta)$ we get $A=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}B$.

Looking at the first components, we get $B=\cos(\theta)$, but looking at the second components we get $B=-\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Can you show your calculations that result in both $B>0$ and $B<0$?

Comment: @md2perpe I added it

Comment: Why do you assert that equality?

Comment: The left-hand-side is the derivative of $\textbf{e}_\phi$. Since $\textbf{e}_\phi$ is an unit vector, its derivative is perpendicular to it. The polar spherical coordinate system is orthogonal, so a vector perpendicular to $\textbf{e}_\phi$ is a linear combination of $\textbf{e}_\theta$ and $\textbf{e}_r$. Hence, $\frac{\partial \textbf{e}_\phi}{\partial \phi}=A \textbf{e}_\theta+B \textbf{e}_r$. Note that A and B are scalars, but not neccessarily constants.

Comment: So $\mathbf{e}_\phi = [\sin(\phi), \cos(\phi), 0]$? That doesn't look correct. Shouldn't it be $\mathbf{e}_\phi = [-\sin(\phi), \cos(\phi), 0]$?

Comment: You're correct, but once you derivate it both components are negative and you can extract the sign outside. The ending combination should stay the same, just multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: Disregard the last comment, I see what you mean. Damn arithmetic errors always get me. Thanks.